# Install VsVim in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsvim

When I try to install VsVim in Visual Studio 2013, I receive the error:

**The installation was unable to install the extension to all the selected products.  For more information, click on the install log link at the bottom of the dialog.
This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.**

```
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM - -------------------------------------------
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM - Initializing Install...
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM - Extension Details...
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -     Identifier      : VsVim.Microsoft.e214908b-0458-4ae2-a583-4310f29687c3
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -     Name            : VsVim
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -     Author          : Jared Parsons
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -     Version         : 1.4.2.0
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -     Description     : VIM emulation layer for Visual Studio
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -     Locale          : en-US
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -     MoreInfoURL     : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -     InstalledByMSI  : False
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.0,5.0]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM - 
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -     Supported Products : 
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -             Version : [10.0]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -             Version : [11.0]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -             Version : [12.0]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -             Version : [10.0]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -             Version : [11.0]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -             Version : [12.0]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -             Version : [10.0]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -             Version : [11.0]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -             Version : [12.0]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -             Version : [10.0]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -             Version : [11.0]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -             Version : [12.0]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -         AtmelStudio
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -             Version : [6.0]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -         AtmelStudio
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -             Version : [6.1]
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM - 
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM -     References      : 
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM - 
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM - Searching for applicable products...
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
11/27/2013 6:32:49 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Any ideas?  I really like this extension!

Comment: Do you have any of the supported editions? It lists them in the error message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have Visual Studio Express 2013 installed.  The express editions do not support extensions so VsVim cannot be installed.  Only the full versions support extensions so you would to buy Visual Studio 2013 to be able to install VsVim.

Comment: @shf301 is correct that this is just a limitation of Visual Studio Express.  There is a user voice request out there to change this to allow Express versions to install extensions that you can vote for https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2086051-allow-extensions-plugins-for-vs-express

Comment: You don't need to buy Visual Studio to enable extensions. There is Visual Studio Community (a free version) available where extensions are allowed: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/free-developer-offers-vs.aspx

Comment: Daan's comment worked for VS-Community-2015. The "Make iPhone/Android apps" at the top of the features list lead me astray, but it seems to just be VS. VsVim installed and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Download](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329) VsVim.

This is a Vim Emulation layer for Visual Studio 2010 and above.  It integrates the familiar key binding experience of Vim directly into Visual Studio's editor.

And this works fine in VS-Community edition also.
To install plugin just double click on `VsVim.vsix`